# link to source control system p4 in redgate tools

Tags: perforce, redgate

hi i am trying to link source control to perforce in redgate tool for sql server management studio but it throws error like

Command:
P4 -c C:\myworkspace_name-LT_2632\webteam\SANDBOXES\sandboxname -s sync "C:\myworkspace_name-LT_2632..."

Output:
error: Client 'C:\myworkspace_name-LT_2632\webteam\SANDBOXES\sandboxname' unknown - use 'client' command to create it.

exit: 1

Comment: The client is unknown, you must use the 'p4 client' command to create it. Are you asking how to use the 'p4 client' command to do that? If not, what precisely is your question?

Comment: Its all about to database link to source control that is perforce ...custom option in red gate tool i am selecting perforce config file....and in that config file i am changed the content " <CommandLine>P4 -s -c myworkspace sync "($ScriptsFolder)..."</CommandLine> "   ...but it does't fetch the data from workspace it directly fetches the p4 depot.     plz help.   thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -c argument to p4 specifies the name of a client workspace. As the error message indicates, you are telling it to run the sync command in a client named 'C:\myworkspace_name-LT_2632\webteam\SANDBOXES\sandboxname'. From your comment on the original question, I think you need to change myworkspace in the example to the name of the client workspace that maps the path you listed.

Comment: thanx for comment .. #Dre Marold- ur ans is useful....actually i am not define my working folder in that workspace root directoty that why this error occurs...i got my answer thank you..